# Quitar salto de linea al crear TXT en PHP

Tags: php

Cuando intento crear un archivo TXT y descargar el mismo desde PHP por alguna razón incluye un salto de linea al inicio del archivo, e intentado quitarlo con `str_replace()` pero no funciona.

El código que estoy ejecutando es simple:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');
header('Content-Type:text/plain');
print trim('HOLA MUNDO);
```

Pueden ejecutar el mismo código y se darán cuenta de que ocurre lo mismo.

Comment: Al código que publicaste le falta una comilla al cerrar el contenido de `trim( )`. Editando eso, funciona como indican en la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

No me pasa, lo probe en http://phptester.net/ y funciona bien. Debe ser alguna configuracion de tu servidor.

Comment: Cómo lo probaste si el código del OP da error así como está?

Comment: Corregi el error de la comilla faltante